# Can I get TypeScript to narrow based on outer function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-narrowing

I would like to have a function that checks to see if X or Y is null, and if not, have TypeScript successfully narrow the types down. Is this possible?

```
const X: string | null
const Y: Record<string, Bar> | null

const checkNull = <T,>(cb:()=>T):T|null => !X || !Y ? null : cb()

const getBar = () => checkNull(()=> Y[X]) << currently says Y and X could be null
```

Comment: What is `Bar`? your constants don't have assignments

Comment: Please [edit] the code to make a [mre] that we can paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.